# How to PUT a nested object into the database using Angular js 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS 1. In my requirement I am trying to upload the data into mongoDB using an API (PUT method). But I am not sure about how to define an nested object. In the form I have address field and it has two nested objects permanent and postal. Below is the format for better understanding.

JSON data:

```
   "address" : {
     "permanent" : {
       "line1" : "geisenheimer",
       "zip" : 14197, 
       "state" : "BW", 
       "Country" : "DE"
     },
     "postal" : {
       "line1" : "Sandwingert",
       "zip" : 69123, 
       "state" : "BW", 
       "Country" : "DE"
     }
   }
```

I want to know the address which I defined in controller if its correct way.

index.html

```
   <form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error.required }">
                  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name as per SSLC marksheet" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.address.$dirty && form.address.$error.required }">
                  <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <label style="padding-top:8px">Permanent Address</label><br>
                      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="permanentfullname" required><br> 
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Address Line 1" ng-model="permanentadd1" required><br> -->
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Address Line1" ng-model="address.permanent.line1" required><br>
                      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="City/Town" ng-model="permanentcity" required><br> -->
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="State" ng-model="address.permanent.state" required><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Zip/Postal code" ng-model="address.permanent.zip" required><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Country" ng-model="address.permanent.country" required><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                      <label style="padding-top:8px">Postal Address</label><br>
                      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="postalFullname" required><br> -->
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 1" ng-model="address.postal.line1" required><br>
                      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 2" ng-model="postaladd2" required><br> -->
                      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="City/Town" ng-model="postalcity" required><br> -->
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="State" ng-model="address.postal.state" required><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Zip/Postal code" ng-model="address.postal.zip" required><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Country" ng-model="address.postal.country" required><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controller.js

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('userProfile.IndexController', function($scope,$http)
{
   // var vm = this; 
   $scope.address = {
    permanent {
        line1: ""
        zip: ""
        state: ""
        country: ""
    },
    postal {
        line1: ""
        zip: ""
        state: ""
        country: ""
    }

   $scope.save  = function()
               { 

                          $http.put('https://student.herokuapp.com/user/personalInfo', 
                            {name : $scope.name,
                             dob : $scope.dob,
                             gender:$scope.gender,
                             line1:$scope.address.permanent.line1,
                             zip:$scope.address.permanent.zip ,
                             state:$scope.address.permanent.state,
                             country:$scope.address.permanent.country,
                             line1:$scope.address.postal.line1,
                             zip:$scope.address.postal.zip ,
                             state:$scope.address.postal.state,
                             country:$scope.address.postal.country
   }).success(function(response)

                            {       
                             console.log(response);  
                             $scope.name= "";
                             $scope.dob= "";
                             $scope.gender= "";
                             $scope.permanent.line1= "";
                             $scope.permanent.zip = "";
                             $scope.permanent.state= "";
                             $scope.permanent.country= "";
                             $scope.postal.line1= "";
                             $scope.postal.zip = "";
                             $scope.postal.state= "";
                             $scope.postal.country= "";

                        }
                        );                                                          


                }
     })
 })();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand the question. It seems your `$scope.address` is already formatted the way you want it.

You should be able to just use the `$scope.address` variable, as it is bound to the object you wish to `PUT`.

`$http.put('https://student.herokuapp.com/user/personalInfo', $scope.address)`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name">
<button ng-click="submitFormAngular()">Calculate</button>
```

and

```
 var app = angular.module('formapp', []);
    app.controller('formctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.name = 'MyName';
        $scope.submitFormAngular = function () {
            var name = $scope.name;
            var data = {};
            data.name = name;
            //var data = { 'id': 10 };
            var url = '/Home/AngularAjax';
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: url,
                data: data //forms user object
                //  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });


        };

    });


            };
```

Comment: I am using PUT method

Comment: ChaNGE METHOD TO ANY       GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,PATCH

Comment: But how is it nested objects?

Comment: any object will do ....just data.obj=obj....try this and console.log(data) before ajax for data is in correct format

Comment: In my case how will i convert it since there is address and it has permanent and postal

Comment: data.address.permanent={
        line1: "line",
        zip: "zip",
        state: "state",
        country: "country"
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127958/discussion-between-heblev-and-syed-mhamudul-hasan-akash).